# How do I efficiently use SQL join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

**Tables**

**Job**

```
JobId, JobName
```

**JobDetail**

```
JobDetailId, JobId, AcctNum, PerformDate
```

One `Job` has many `JobDetails` linked by `JobId`.

For certain `JobNames`, (JobeName1, JobName2) I want a list with **ONLY one `JobDetail`** where `Performdate` is within last 6 months.

For the criteria above I should get two records. What is the correct SQL statement?

I have gotten as far as this and am not get just getting the correct statement.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(J.JobId) 
FROM 
    Job J  
WHERE 
    J.JobName IN ('Doc1', 'Doc2')
GROUP BY 
    J.JobName
```

**[EDIT]**
SQL Server 2005

**[EDIT2]**

```
SELECT 
    J.JobName, JD.AcctNum 
FROM 
    Job J  
JOIN JobDetail JD ON J.JobId = JD.JobId
WHERE 
    J.JobName IN ('DOC1', 'DOC2')
GROUP BY 
    J.JobName
```

This statement is producing:

J.JobId is invalid in the select list...not contained in aggregate function..

**[EDIT3]**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ef21/1/0

I want most recent AcctNum by PerformDate for Doc1 & DOC2.

So, from the data in SQLFIDDLE, I should get 2 ROWS back one for each of the JobName.

**[EDIT4]**
My expected data is * rows from JobDetail table:
JobDetailId 1
jobDetailId 3

Comment: Mention your DBMS too. Like SQL Server, mysql, oracle etc.

Comment: Second statement produces J.JobId is invalid in the select list...not contained in aggregate function..

Comment: @Picflight - It would be great if you could also put in your sample input and your expected output from the sqlfiddle.

Comment: Check your sqlfiddle. You had two `DOC2`. I have corrected it. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
SELECT COUNT(J.JobId) FROM Job J  
INNER JOIN JobDetails D ON J.JobId = D.JobId
WHERE J.JobName IN ('Jobname1', 'Jobname2') 
AND D.PerformDate >= DateAdd(mm, -6, getdate())
GROUP BY J.JobName
```

I have written this in TSQL (SQL Server). For other DBMS you will have to use the relevant function for `DateAdd(mm, -6, getdate())`.

**Update:** To pick the latest `AcctNum` for `DOC1` and `DOC2`.

```
Select D.JobID, Acctnum from 
    JobDetail D Inner Join
    (
     SELECT J.JOBID, MAX(PerformDate) as LatestPerformDate FROM Job J
     INNER JOIN JobDetail D ON J.JobId = D.JobId
     WHERE J.JobName IN ('DOC1', 'DOC2') 
     Group by J.JobID
    ) X on D.JobID = X.JobID
    And D.PerformDate = X.LatestPerformDate
```

**Update 2:** When `DOC2` can appear twice in `Job` table with different `JobID`.

```
Select D.JobID, Acctnum from 
JobDetail D Inner Join Job J on J.JobID = D.JobID
Inner join
(
 SELECT J.JOBname, MAX(PerformDate) as LatestPerformDate FROM Job J  
 INNER JOIN JobDetail D ON J.JobId = D.JobId
 WHERE J.JobName IN ('DOC1', 'DOC2')
 group by j.jobname
) X on J.JobName = X.JobName
And D.PerformDate = X.LatestPerformDate
```

Output from the posted input data in sqlfiddle in the question:

```
JOBID   ACCTNUM
--------------------
 1      1235
 4      1238
```

Comment: This query returns 3 rows, I should get only two, the latest for each of the DOC1 & DOC2.

Comment: @Picflight - This is because in your sqlfiddle, you have two `DOC2`. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51956/16 and compare with your sqlfiddle. Check your insert statements in your sqlfiddle(the one that you have posted in your question)

Comment: I see what you mean, but my insert are intended, DOC2 can appear twice in JOB.JobName. There can be more that one Job record for each of the DOC1 or DOC2..

Comment: @Picflight - I see, that is very odd. Anyways, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT j.*, d.*
FROM Job j
JOIN (SELECT JobId, MAX(PerformDate) maxDate
      FROM JobDetail
      WHERE PerformDate > DATEADD(mm, -6, GETDATE())
      GROUP BY JobId) md
ON j.JobId = md.JobId
JOIN JobDetail d
ON d.JobId = md.JobId AND d.PerformDate = md.maxDate
WHERE j.JobName IN ('DOC1', 'DOC2');
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ef21/12)

Comment: I don't think this fulfils the "ONLY one JobDetail" requirement noted by the OP. This will return ALL JobDetail records within the specified interval.

Comment: @RJLohan The `GROUP BY` clause makes it return one for each name.

Comment: True enough, my apologies.

Comment: @Barmar -- without knowing the RDBMS, this may not compile.  If Mysql, then this will work.  However, if almost any other RDBMS, then it won't...

Comment: @sgeddes True enough. Most of the clueless SQL users seem to be using MySQL, so this has a good chance of being right. If he updates the question to state his DBMS, and it's not MySQL, I'll delete or update my answer.

Comment: MS SQL 2005; I get the following when I try the query. J.JobId is invalid in the select list...not contained in aggregate function..

Comment: Try the new version. I arbitrarily chose `MAX(PerformDate)` to get a single row.

Comment: Still getting  J.JobId is invalid in the select list...not contained in aggregate function..

Comment: Got rid of the unnecessary GROUP BY at the end

Comment: Now I dont get any rows back :-(

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: +1 for introducing sqlfiddle to me, added link in main questions.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the fiddle, but I should be expecting JobDetailId 1
jobDetailId 3

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to do that in SQL-Server, I only know how to do it in MySQL, which is less strict about GROUP BY.